# Query-not getting right answer

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I want to used group by so that I can get data as `country-state-district`. I want only display the country then state and a district level want to add checkbox.

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('country_name,s_name,dist_name');
$this->db->from('resource_details');    
$this->db->join('location','reso_dtail_location=loc_id');        
$this->db->join('go_state', 'go_stste_id = loc_state', 'left');
$this->db->join('go_country', 'num = loc_country', 'left');
$this->db->join('go_dist', 'id = loc_district', 'left');
$this->db->where('loc_id !=1 AND loc_id !=2');

$query = $this->db->get();

    //result
$location = $query->result();
```

but the query does not give right answer after using `group_by` it only shows 1st record

Comment: what you want to do? not unsderstand

Comment: i didn't see `group_by` anywhere in code?

Comment: please check your query with `echo $this->db->last_query()` and what's the error/result you are getting and what's result you want ?

Comment: i used group_by after  $this->db->where('loc_id !=1 AND loc_id !=2'); but result is not getting so i am removed it

Comment: @riya can you elobarate more about this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use group by country. So that you can get distinct country name. But states and city you can use group concat.